# Does "This is so tight!" in this scene mean "This is so cool!"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

Below is a part of the dialogue between a little girl named Max and a woman named Carey in the TV series "The Suite Life of Zack & Cody" - season 1 episode 1:

> ...
> (It's the first time Max came into Carey's room. Max saw and came to some audio equipment on the desk)
> Max: This is so tight!
> Carey: I was just rehearsing for my new show.
> ...

I checked meanings of the word 'tight' on this website https://www.thefreedictionary.com/tight, but I couldn't find a suitable meaning for this scene.

I guess "This is so tight!" means "This is so cool!" in this case. Is my guess correct?
[image]

Comment: [Urban Dictionary:](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Tight) **Tight** The late 90's/2000 ***term for something that is cool.*** But it's got next to no currency, so don't bother committing it to memory (hopefully most people would be able to *guess* the intended sense in the example here, and there won't be many of them anyway). I seriously doubt this particular usage (perhaps derived from ***tight musical performances*** with split-second timing accuracy?) will ever appear in many if any mainstream dictionaries.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That sounds like an answer to me. See also [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tight#Adjective), sense 5: "(slang) Extraordinarily great or special." The word immediately makes me think of the YouTube channel [Pitch Meeting](https://www.youtube.com/@PitchMeetings), where its use is a recurring joke.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Urban Dictionary:](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Tight) has an entry for **tight** saying it's...

> *The late 90's/2000 term for something that is cool.*

Hopefully most people would be able to guess the intended sense in the example here, and there won't be many of them anyway. But it's got next to no currency, so don't bother committing it to memory.

The usage *may* derive from "tight" *musical performances* (multiple players coordinating with split-second timing accuracy). But I seriously doubt this particular usage  will ever appear in many (if any) mainstream dictionaries.